# How to write query in kibana Devtool for showing all indexes

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, search, kibana

I'm trying to write a query in Kibana DevTools that would give me list of index present in elastic search so how to write query in kibana devtool
GET /.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GET _cat/indices
```

And that is not query.

use    `_cat API`
for getting elasticsearch cluster and indices stats.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html